# changing the color of hamburger icon in a responsive sticky nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to change the color of a hamburger menu in a sticky nav for a responsive website.

At the moment, the nav bar and menus are styled and toggled with css and js.

Everything thing works fine, but recently i've had to make some changes and have run into this problem.

This is how it works;
- the nav bar sticks to the top of the screen and changes color on scroll.
- On narrow width screens, some js hides the menu text links and toggles a hamburger menu.
- on clicking the hamburger menu, an overlay menu is toggled

The problem i'm having is I've changed the background color of the sticky menu bar on scroll - but I can't see how to change the color of the hamburger icon on scroll.

here's what I have...

```
<!-- Script Sticky Menu -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
           if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
               document.getElementById("main-nav").className = "scrolling";
           } else {
               document.getElementById("main-nav").className = "";
        }

           if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
               document.getElementById("nav-page-section").className = "scrolling";
           } else {
               document.getElementById("nav-page-section").className = "";
        }

           if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
               document.getElementById("vb-logo-mobile").className = "scrolling";
           } else {
               document.getElementById("vb-logo-mobile").className = "";
           }
        })
        </script>
```

Inside "nav-page-section" is a container for the hamburger button...

```
<div class="button_container" id="toggle">
    <span class="top"></span>
    <span class="middle"></span>
    <span class="bottom"></span>
</div>
```

This css styles the button_container...

```
.button_container span {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

Initially, i added an additional line to the script...

```
    if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
        document.getElementsByClassName("button_container").className = "scrolling";
    } else {
        document.getElementsByClassName("button_container").className = "";
    }
```

And added this css styling...

```
.button_container.scrolling {
  background: #E4002B; 
  color: #E4002B; 
}
```

But that hasn't worked. I searched around for a way to target a specific tag ('span') within a classname ('button_container') but didn't find anything.

I keep looking at the span tag and thinking that's what's tripping me up - but i've tried many different variations of the script and nothing seems to work. When i add [0] after the classname - ('button_container')[0] - the hamburger menu disappears.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks.

Here is the full CSS and HTML...

```
/* 7. Main Menu - Hamburger */

/* icon+overlay */
.overlay-menu ul li a {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'HurmeGeometricSans1';
  font-weight: 200;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 5px;
}
.overlay-menu ul li a:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background: #E4002B;
  height: 2px;
  width: 0%;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
          transform: translateX(-50%);
  left: 50%;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: .35s ease;
}
.overlay-menu ul li a:hover:after, .overlay-menu ul li a:focus:after, .overlay-menu ul li a:active:after {
  width: 100%;
}

.button_container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 18px;
  right: 18px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 100;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
}
.button_container:hover {
  opacity: .7;
}

.button_container.active .top {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
          transform: translateY(11px) translateX(0) rotate(45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container.active .middle {
  opacity: 0;
  background: #FFF;
}
.button_container.active .bottom {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
          transform: translateY(-11px) translateX(0) rotate(-45deg);
  background: #FFF;
}

.button_container span {
  background: #fff;
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: all .35s ease;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.button_container.scrolling {
  background: #E4002B; 
  color: #E4002B; 
}

.button_container span:nth-of-type(2) {
  top: 11px;
}
.button_container span:nth-of-type(3) {
  top: 22px;
}


<!-- start Hamburger Menu & Overlay Menu -->
              <div class="button_container" id="toggle">
                  <span class="top"></span>
                  <span class="middle"></span>
                  <span class="bottom"></span>
              </div>

              <div class="overlay" id="overlay">
                  <nav class="overlay-menu">
                      <ul>
                          <li><a href="vwear.html">V:WEAR</a></li>
                          <li><a href="vgear.html">V:GEAR</a></li>
                          <li><a href="mechs.html">V:MECHS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="rdas.html">V:RDAS</a></li>
                          <li><a href="vliquids.html">V:LIQUID</a></li>
                      </ul>
                  </nav>
              </div>
              <!-- end Hamburger Menu & Overlay Menu -->
```

Comment: Where is the css (or html) for the hamburger itself? It might be a _after_ or _before_ pseudo element. Then there is something like `::after` or `::before` in your css containing icon-font content. Please add some info a working example.

Comment: the hamburger is not an icon-font, it's just some css;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand the *spans* in the *button_container* are the bars of the hamburger menu. So, to change color on scroll, I would say:

```
.scrolling .button_container span { 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Replace `red` with the preferred color.

Comment: omg. so simple. worked! thank you so much Teuniz!!! Just shows I suck at html/css :)

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button_container").className
```

won't work since

```
document.getElementsByClassName("button_container")
```

is an array, and you have to iterate the array and assign to element you want.

```
if(window.pageYOffset > 50){
    document.getElementsByClassName("button_container")[0].className = "scrolling";
} else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("button_container")[0].className = "";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I discovered that. What I thought I could do was combine a getElementsByClassName with getElementsByTag since I want to target the 'span' tag of the button_container' class - but can't figure that out either...